Commutation of $r$ and $p$ in second quantization
I am currently working through the first chapter of Molecular Electronic-Structure Theory (Helgaker et al.). They are demonstrating that, in a complete basis set, commutation relations that hold for operators in their first quantization representation also hold for those operators in their second quantization representation. Using their notation, in first quantization:
$$[r_{\alpha}^c, p_{\beta}^c] = i\delta_{\alpha\beta}^c$$
where
\begin{align}
r_{\alpha}^c&=\sum_{j=1}^N r_{\alpha}^c(j)\\
p_{\alpha}^c&=\sum_{j=1}^N p_{\alpha}^c(j)\\
\delta_{\alpha\beta}^c&=\sum_{j=1}^N \delta_{\alpha\beta}(j)
\end{align}
and the Greek letters index cartesian directions. The corresponding second quantization representation of $r_{\alpha}^c$, for instance, would be
$$\hat{r}_{\alpha}=\sum_{PQ}[r_{\alpha}^c]_{PQ}\,a_{P}^{\dagger}a_{Q}$$
where $a_{P}^{\dagger}$, $a_{Q}$ are the creation/annihilation operators, respectively, and
$$[r_{\alpha}^c]_{PQ}=\int\phi_{P}^*(x)\,r_{\alpha}^c\,\phi_{Q}(x)dx$$
for spin orbitals $\phi_P(x)$, $\phi_Q(x)$. My issue is near the last line of their derivation (1.5.31). In a complete basis set, they state that:
\begin{align}
[\hat{r}_{\alpha}, \hat{p}_{\beta}] &= \sum_{P,Q=1}^{\infty} [[r_{\alpha}^c, p_{\beta}^c]]_{PQ}\,a_{P}^{\dagger}a_{Q}\\
&= \sum_{P,Q=1}^{\infty} [i\delta_{\alpha\beta}^c]_{PQ}\,a_{P}^{\dagger}a_{Q}\\
&= i\delta_{\alpha\beta}\hat{N}
\end{align}
where $\hat{N} = \sum_Pa_{P}^{\dagger}a_{P}$ is the number operator. These last two lines are giving me trouble. I understand that a $\delta_{PQ}$ comes out of $[\delta_{\alpha\beta}^c]_{PQ}$ due to the orthonormality of the spin orbitals, which collapses the P,Q sum into $\hat{N}$. However, I do not understand how $\delta_{\alpha\beta}^c$ becomes $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$, as $\delta_{\alpha\beta}^c$ is not at all affected by the integral and should just be able to be pulled out entirely (this is what happens to get the $\delta_{PQ}$ in the first place!). I feel like I am missing something very basic.
Thanks!

It need not be affected by the integral. If the cartesian directions do not match, the commutator inside the sum vanishes, and so does the entire r.h.s. So the $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$ is justified, since the l.h.s. is zero unless the Cartesian subscripts match.

Thank you for the response, and I do understand this. However, if the cartesian directions match then, as $\delta_{\alpha\beta}^{c}$ is a sum of $N$ $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$, this would produce an additional factor of $N$ in the final result that is not there. I just do not understand why the $\delta_{\alpha\beta}^c$ is reduced to the single delta (although their result matches what I would expect from the result in first quantization).

@frobenius Hello, mate. I'm sorry about my answer not being complete. Let's see if this helps. The second-quantized operators you are considering here are symmetric one particle operators, since they are a sum of operators each acting on the single-particle Hilbert of a given particle, with the same phase. The matrix elements appearing in the second-quantized expansion of the operator are taken in the single-particle space, and hence the commutator whose matrix element you have inside the sum is referred to a single-particle. No sum over particles. You may check how these are built in Landau's

In Landau's book on Non-relativistic Quantum Mechanics, I mean. This is the same for two-particle operators. For bosons, the matrix element multiplying the creation/annihilation operators in the expansion would be taken in the two-particle Hilbert factor of the Fock space, for example. In your example, It's a matrix element on single-particle orbitals. Here, the problem is the notation is a little bit confusing, since you use the same symbol for the single-particle position operator and for the symmetric sum of position operators of the $N$ particles.

Just for completion allow me to give you a glimpse of where the matrix elements come from. In a theory built on vectors of identical particles living in Fock's space, one may take a symmetric sum of the single-particle operators as you did. One may transform the basis of orbitals chosen and its creation/annihilation operators to the basis of orbitals that diagonalize the single-particle operator in the one-particle space. This way one realizes that the matrix elements of the symmetric sum of single-particle operators is just the sum over "eigenorbitals" of the corresponding eigenvalues times

the occupation number. Going back to the original basis of orbitals reveals the second-quantized expression you brought, and the matrix element over single-particle orbitals emerges naturally. This is the origin of it. In the process one changes the sum over particles to a sum over orbitals.

Ah, I see! So the $[r_{\alpha}^c]{PQ}$ is just referring to the one-particle operator and not the sum of the one particle operators? It is still strange, however, that they specifically use $\delta{\alpha\beta}^c$ in the commutator of the supposedly one-particle operators, when $\delta_{\alpha\beta}^c$ is defined to be a sum over particles of the standard $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$. I wonder if this could even just be a typo (i.e. no superscript $c$ in the second-to-last line)? I think I do understand, however, that the $[r_{\alpha}^c]_{PQ}$ is a one particle operator (as we sum over orbitals).

@frobenius I agree. It is strange. Maybe it is a typo.

Thanks for helping to confirm my suspicions. I cannot find any page containing errata in the book; perhaps I will try to contact the authors. It also definitely makes sense that the $[r_{\alpha}^c]_{PQ}$ should be referring to the single-particle operators (not the entire sum) as a one particle operator is defined as $\hat{O} = \sum_i \hat{o}(i)$, so the integral would be over the $\hat{o}$; not sure how I missed this!
